# Clean vertex group to keep one single vertex group

Tags: weight-painting

I generated the rig of a model with Auto Rig Pro which works great.
For the jaw, as my model is basic, I need only one vertex group for the jaw bone.
I tried to use the "Clean vertex group" function in weight paint mode, but is is greyed out.

[image]

Here is an image of an attempt with a (very) basic example. The function is greyed out still.
What's wrong ?

If you also have a suggestion about the way I can affect the jaw deformation to a single bone, I am interested ...

Thanks !

Comment: To affect the jaw deformation to a single bone, obviously, it is possible to manually delete the useless vertex groups : all but the jaw group. But the Clean vertex group function would be usefull in more complex situations.